# select in Angular2

Tags: angular, select

I have to do Login and I need select option. Can me help someone where I make mistake?
There is my code

```js
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'tenants',
    template:`<select name="repeatSelect"  id="repeatSelect" [(ngModel)]="model.tenant">
      <option *ngFor="let tenant of tenants" value="{{tenant.abbr}}">{{tenant.name}}</option>
    </select>`
})



export class TenantComponent implements OnInit {
    model: any = {};
    loading = false;
    error = '';
    public tenants: Tenant[];

    constructor(

        private tenantService: TenantService) { }

    setTenant(){
        //if you're on older versions of ES, use for-in instead
        var tenant = this.tenants.find(t => t.name);

        if(tenant) { this.model.tenant = tenant; }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loading = true;

        this.tenantService.tenants()
            .subscribe((result : Tenant[]) => {
                this.tenants = result;
            });
    }
}
```

and Then I insert  in Login template.

If I choose one of the Options. In HTML of the Side is[image]

after I chose option and sent Request for Login. It doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: You should rather use : `[value]="tenant.abbr"` instead of `value="{{tenant.abbr}}"`

Comment: That shouldn't matter if `tenant.abbr` is a string value.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTenant(){
        //if you're on older versions of ES, use for-in instead
        var tenant = this.tenants.find(t => t.name);

        if(tenant) { this.model.tenant = tenant; }
    }
```

This part of the code looks VERY strange.

`this.tenants.find(t => t.name)` misses some boolean expression. You need to compare t.name with the name you selected like `t.name == selectedName`. That way the tenant will always be `null`, because `find` expects some boolean expression to find something!

Comment: I don't use this part of code. I forgot to delete it

Comment: The we are missing some information. What does happen to your model.tenant? Is it null when you log it? What does happen in your login-template after selecting the value?

Comment: where should I log it? I deleted setTenant() methode. My Login has username, password and attribute from tenant Tenant(it is an object)

Answer (score 0):

`[(ngModel)]="model.tenant"` is referring a `Tenant` object but `value="{{tenant.abbr}}"` is referring to a string.

I think it should rather be

```ts
template:`
<select name="repeatSelect"  id="repeatSelect" [(ngModel)]="model.tenant">
  <option *ngFor="let tenant of tenants" [ngValue]="tenant">{{tenant.name}}</option>
</select>`
```

`[ngValue]` allows to use object values with `<option>`

Comment: Hard to tell without more information. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?